# Auto Generate fields values for testing a form using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, integration-testing, protractor

I want to test a simple user registration form using Protractor.

Here's my test:

```
describe('User Registration Page Tests', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('/#/register');
    });

    it('user registration success', function(){
        element(by.model('user.organizationName')).sendKeys('someOrg');
        element(by.model('user.firstName')).sendKeys('some');
        element(by.model('user.lastName')).sendKeys('user');
        element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('some@user.com');
        element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('123456');
        element(by.model('confirmPassword')).sendKeys('123456');

        element(by.id('submitBtn')).click();

        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            expect(url).toEqual('http://localhost:9001/#/success');     
        });
    });
});
```

For the first time, the test will pass. But for the next times it will fail because this user is already exist.

Is there a way to auto generate new fields values to solve this issue?

Couldn't find anything in Google about it...

Answer (score 4):

Add the current timestamp to the values for firstName and lastName as,

```
var randVal = Date.now()
............................
element(by.model('user.firstName')).sendKeys('some-' + randVal);
element(by.model('user.lastName')).sendKeys('user-' + randVal);
element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('some' + randVal + '@user.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can use this function to Auto-generate username**

```
var.autoGenerateUserName = function() {
        var autoGenerateUserName = "Auto-UserName-";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            autoGenerateUserName += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        return  autoGenerateUserName;
    };
```

**In this form registration you can use something like this**

```
element(by.model('user.organizationName')).sendKeys(autoGenerateUserName());
```

**or**

```
var userName = autoGenerateUserName();  

element(by.model('user.organizationName')).sendKeys(userName);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can randomly create strings, but I was wondering if there's another solution for this. Chrome has some extensions that auto fill fields so I thought maybe there is something similar for code